# How to set a new height (or width) to a CRect?

Tags: c++, mfc

**How do you change the height (or width) of a MFC** `CRect`, without moving the rectangle (top left static) ?

It seems there is no direct setter to the (calculated) height ( `int CRect::Height()` ).

The current way I find is to recalculate the bottom:

```cpp
// Create a 40 x 40 rectangle
CRect myRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
// Set the Height to 80
myRect.bottom = myRect.top + 80;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/crect-class?view=msvc-170#inflaterect might be what you want, but I'd prefer to do it the way you've shown.

Comment: You're right, the height is a derived property not a direct member so there's no way to set it.  The method you're using looks fine.

Comment: Your code is fine.

Comment: OO is great - `class CMyRect : public CRect; CMyRect::SetHeight(int iNewHeight);  // maintains top, sets bottom based on top  CMyRect:AdjustHeight(int iDelta);  // bumps bottom` etc.

Answer (score 4):

A [`RECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect) in Windows programming is a structure that stores values for `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` (conventionally endpoint exclusive). The width and height are derived values (`right - left` and `bottom - top`, respectively).

There is no API to change the width (or height) directly since that would be an ambiguous operation: Should a hypothetical `SetWidth()` API grow or shrink towards the left? The right? Or maintain the center?

MFC's [`CRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/crect-class) class merely encapsulates a `RECT` and provides some convenience members (such as [`Height()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/crect-class#height)) but not much more. If you want to increase the height of a `CRect` either add to its `bottom` or subtract from its `top`. If you want to set the height to a specific value update the value opposite to the one you wish to keep stable (as you're doing in the question already).

Calling [`NormalizeRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/crect-class#normalizerect) is a good idea if you cannot otherwise ensure that `left` is less than or equal to `right` and `top` is less than or equal to `bottom`.

Comment: Ambiguous, Yes. And there is a Shrink method to grow in whatever direction. But nothing to formulate it by total size... sad.